# SQL server remote access from and C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my server and a C# application on Network Drive.

When I am running this application on server, it is working fine. But the problem occurs when I am running the application from client machines.

It does not connect to the server. I get the following error

> Network related specific error..

Can anyone give me any solution ?

Connection string used:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="Truly_Paste_Solution.Win.Properties.Settings.TrulyDBAConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TrulyDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: **SHOW US** some code, your connection string etc. - without **anything** - should should we know what's wrong?? We can't see your screen - nor read your mind!! You need to help us help you!

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Truly_Paste_Solution.Win.Properties.Settings.TrulyDBAConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TrulyDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: Two things: first, SQL Server **Express** by default doesn't allow remote connections - search this site, there are **tons** of questions and answers how to enable this. Second: `server=.\sqlexpress` means SQL Server **Express** on the **local machine** - that of course doesn't work for remote clients! You need to use the **machine name** (or IP address) of the computer where your SQL Server is installed on!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different possible causes to get that kind of error -

- Make sure your server's firewall settings allow remote host to connect
- Make sure are connecting to the correct port of SQL Server which can be specified in the conecttiuon string
- Make sure you have SQL or Mixed mode authentication enabled depending upon what scheme you use.

[more things to check](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

What's your connection string ? 
Did you connect the SQL Server by IP ? 
Is there any firewall or Rules on your Server ?

Assuming your Server Lan IP address is 192.169.1.199 and your are running on MSSQL Server, so your connection string should be like :

```
Data Source=192.168.1.199;Initial Catalog=somedatabase;uid=yourid;pwd=yourpassword
```

Read about how to enable TCP/IP protocol connection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)